# ignore the joomla tag or consider them as valid tag in netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, joomla, dtd

While developing joomla projects in netbeans ,
it consider the joomla tag like:

```
<jdoc:includes type="modules" name="kkk" />
```

as invalid tag,
is there any method to modify the html dtd or ignore some of tags in netbeans?

Comment: NetBeans uses the schema/DTD you provide to determine if a tag is valid, so are you sure you have the right schema/DTD?

Comment: normaly i put this on the top of the html `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: Do you also have `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ...`?

Comment: yes my problem is with the joomla special tag and not the xhtml tag

Answer (score 0):

This has been added to the Netbeans bug tracker already.

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=207296